# How should I convert a list into 2-D int[][] array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list ;
 int size = list.size();

         int[][] iArray = new int[size][size];
for (int i=0; i<size; ++i){
             for (j = 0; j<size; ++j){
                 iArray[i][j] = list.get(j +( list.size() * i)); 
     }
}
```

**I'm using the following code but it gives me error. please suggest.**

Comment: youre trying to create a 2D array of size 0x0...

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Why do you say that?

Comment: Which is the error? You should provide as many details as possible when asking a question if you want people to help you. Even if you loaded the list with appropriate values, you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. In `list.get(j +( list.size() * i))` you are exceeding the bounds of your list. E. g. if the list size is 10, i will loop from 0 to 9. Suppose i is 2. Then `list.size() * i` is 20 and even if j is 0, you will be asking for the 20th item in the list, which does not exist.

Comment: You must specify variable type j in forloop

       for (int j = 0; j<size; ++j){
                 iArray[i][j] = list.get(j +( list.size() * i)); 
             }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a 2D list, you just need two loops to convert it to a 2D array.

Now, since Java doesn't actually support 2D lists/arrays, those are actually lists of lists, to be converted to arrays of arrays, and the sub-lists/arrays don't necessarily all have the same size.

So, to support a [jagged 2D list/array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array), create each sub-array individually from the corresponding sub-list, like this:

```
int[][] iArray = new int[list.size()][]; // create outer array
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> subList = list.get(i);
    iArray[i] = new int[subList.size()]; // create sub-array
    for (int j = 0; j < subList.size(); j++)
        iArray[i][j] = subList.get(j);   // copy value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting?
the problem could be that your inner ArrayList is smaler then the outer one.
the other way around it wouldnt cause an error but your 2D Array would be incomplete.
and you have an syntax error in the inner for loop your j doenst have an variable type
you have to do something like this

```
    int iOuterSize = list.size();
    int iBiggestInnerSize = -1;
    for (ArrayList<Integer> arrayList : list) {
        int iCurInnerSize = arrayList.size();
        if (iCurInnerSize > iBiggestInnerSize) {
            iBiggestInnerSize = iCurInnerSize;
        }
    }
    int[][] iArray = new int[iOuterSize][iBiggestInnerSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < iOuterSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).size(); j++) {
            iArray[i][j] = list.get(i).get(j);
        }
    }
```